# How to console all reducers? reactjs

Tags: reactjs, console, redux

Have A file with store.js

```
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import axios from 'axios';
import chalk from 'chalk';
import Immutable from 'immutable';
import type { Store } from '../types';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

export default (history: Object, initialState: Object = {}): Store => {
  const middlewares = [
    thunk.withExtraArgument(axios),
    routerMiddleware(history),
  ];



  const enhancers = [
    applyMiddleware(...middlewares),
    __DEV__ && typeof window === 'object' && typeof window.devToolsExtension !== 'undefined' ?
      window.devToolsExtension({
          serialize: {
              immutable: Immutable
          }
      }) : f => f,
  ];

    const devToolEnhancers = __DEV__ && typeof window === 'object' && typeof window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ !== 'undefined' ?
        window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({
            serialize: {
                immutable: Immutable
            }
        }) : f => f;

   const immutableState  = Immutable.fromJS(initialState)
  const store: Store = createStore(rootReducer, immutableState, compose(...enhancers));



  if (module.hot) {
    // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
    module.hot.accept('./reducers', () => {
      try {
        const nextReducer = require('./reducers').default;

        store.replaceReducer(nextReducer);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(chalk.red(`==>   Reducer hot reloading error ${error}`));
      }
    });
  }



  return store;
};
```

I need to enable console.log of all reducers

I found this code:

```
const logger = store => next => action => {
  console.group(action.type)
  console.info('dispatching', action)
  let result = next(action)
  console.log('next state', store.getState())
  console.groupEnd(action.type)
  return result
}

let createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(logger)(createStore)

let yourApp = combineReducers(reducers)
let store = createStoreWithMiddleware(yourApp)
```

but I don't know how to combine it. Need to console previos and next state of rudecer. try many variations but can't do this

Comment: You can try play with "Redux Dev Tool";)

Comment: Use https://github.com/evgenyrodionov/redux-logger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try 'redux-logger' middleware. It will log the prevState and nextState in console.

```
import createLogger from 'redux-logger';

const middlewares = [
    thunk.withExtraArgument(axios),
    routerMiddleware(history),
    createLogger()
  ];
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: middleware is not a function

Comment: Can you add the line no and file name where you are getting this error. A stack trace will also work.

Comment: **Redux Logger** changed it's API recently. Now it must be imported with curly braces: `import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';`. See Usage in the [official reference](https://github.com/evgenyrodionov/redux-logger#usage).